# Background неправильной формы на Landing Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Всем доброго дня**

Начнем с того, что я вроде как не новичок в этой области. Работаю с front-end достаточно долго. Но вот сейчас есть вопрос. Возможно он глупый и после гугления я как то не нашел на него ответ.

**Сам вопрос**

Вы видели когда нибудь lp, у которого на заливке затененное фото, и при том оно залито в фигуру неправильной формы. Это не просто прямоугольник – это вообще без проблем. Я говорю про треугольные или трапеционные(хз, трапеция короче). Как это вообще реально сделать? Если учесть, что контент внутри может быть расширяемым. Если уж с расширяемым никак, то как сделать хотя бы фиксом? Как пример того, о чем я говорю - прикладываю скрин.

Стоит учесть, что так сделан ВЕСЬ lp. С разными заливками и наклоном стыка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реально с CSS3, растянуть нужную фигуру, она может быть любого размера с помощью

```
transform: skew(0deg, -5deg);
```

вот пример на фидле:
https://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/9thzrwey/2/

Comment: Вариант подойдет, если вас устроит деформация фона, который тоже подвержен влиянию `skew`

Comment: на примере автора фон вобще одноцветный, так что там искажений никаких не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не было деформации фона при преобразовании блока - можно использовать `clip-path`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 1px dashed #d11d05;
  padding: 20px;
}

section.-bg-first {
  background: #bada55 url('http://sunflowercet.org/b/wp-content/plugins/fancy-text-widget/images/ftw-body-horizontal-lines-paper.png');
}
section.-bg-second {
  background: #fb1 url('http://sunflowercet.org/b/wp-content/plugins/fancy-text-widget/images/ftw-body-horizontal-lines-paper.png');
}

section.-skew-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
section.-skew-top {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="-bg-first -skew-bottom">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni labore voluptatum fuga molestias quasi, quidem quia cupiditate assumenda sunt rem. Et doloribus hic dicta, necessitatibus illum veritatis possimus inventore minima?</div>
</section>
<section class="-bg-second -skew-top -skew-bottom">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni labore voluptatum fuga molestias quasi, quidem quia cupiditate assumenda sunt rem. Et doloribus hic dicta, necessitatibus illum veritatis possimus inventore minima?</div>
</section>
<section class="-bg-first -skew-top">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni labore voluptatum fuga molestias quasi, quidem quia cupiditate assumenda sunt rem. Et doloribus hic dicta, necessitatibus illum veritatis possimus inventore minima?</div>
</section>
```

[Или посмотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/mmc19eka/)

> Но нужно учесть [совместимость с браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). В браузерах без поддержки `clip-path` края будут ровные, а у секций верхние отступы будут больше нижних:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правда печально, что, действительно, поддержка не самая хорошая. На FF вроде даже на новых версиях нет поддержки.